# How may I set category in NUnit 3 in GUI

Tags: nunit

I have the following code:

```
[TestFixture]
    class A: B
    {
      [Test(Description = "SW"), Category("Minimum")]
        public void TS1()
        {
        }
    }

[TestFixture]
    class C: B
    {
      [Test(Description = "ex"), Category("Minimum")]
        public void TS2()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the GUI of NUnit 3.0.1, filter test, and category I get only one test in the Minimum category and not 2 tests in the Minimum category. (the other test is under None category although it's under Minimum)

How may I get the correct filter?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug, which you can report at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui/issues.

That said, since the GUI is not yet released there could be an issue in how you are building it. You should also keep in mind that the source for the GUI may depend on a version of NUnit that has not yet been released.

Even when we do release a binary, it will be called 0.1 and will be mainly for the purpose of getting feedback on usability of the GUI.

The NUnit team is very conservative about recommending use of our pre-alpha source code in production use - that is, we don't recommend it. :-)

All that said, if it's a problem, we like to hear about it. :-)